# usage of ec2 "modify_image_attribute" with OrganizationArn in LaunchPermission

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Going through boto3 document with usage of ec2 `modify_image_attribute`, I'd like to share an image to aws Organization

Here is my code for testing

```
import boto3

imageId="ami-xxxx"
organizationArn="arn:aws:organizations::<org_account>:organization/o-<org_id>"

ec2=boto3.client('ec2')
ec2.modify_image_attribute(
    ImageId = imageId,
    LaunchPermission = {
        'Add' : [{ 'OrganizationArn': organizationArn}]
    }
)
```

I got error

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in LaunchPermission.Add[0]: "OrganizationArn", must be one of: Group, UserId
%
```

refer: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_image_attribute

[image]

anything I missed?

Comment: Closed it, it is my environment issue. after upgrade boto3 to latest (1.22.4), above code works. the boto3 version used to be 1.18.x

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept the answer as well.